# How to prevent sleeping in Android

Tags: android, sleep

I 'm working with GPS in my application. When phone go to sleep, the GPS's data don't update. I want to stay phone screen wake up until my app will be close. How can I prevent sleeping in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent an Android phone from going to sleep programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-can-i-prevent-an-android-phone-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`WakeLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). Bear in mind that using a `WakeLock` for a long period of time will drain the battery, which your users may not appreciate.

Comment: Is this the same method you would use to keep the screen on during a game?

Comment: @Kratz: Probably not. Use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in an attribute of some widget in the game layout.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could it possible to do something like that using Javascript in a web page?

Comment: @sємsєм: No, sorry, unless you are using a `WebView` to display it and are exposing `WakeLock` or `setKeepScreenOn()` functionality via `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to have the GPS related stuff running as a service in the background so you don't have to keep the screen active.

Comment: With wakelocks you can decide whether you just need the CPU to be on or the screen as well - [more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)