# Stop android device from sleeping

Tags: android, image, sleep

I'm trying to develop a very simple app that displays like a slideshow of images which Im sure ill be able to figure out (if anyone has any advice would be much appreciated) but what im wondering is there any way I can stop the device from going to sleep if its left cycling through these images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to prevent android phone from going to sleep using my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/i-want-to-prevent-android-phone-from-going-to-sleep-using-my-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using

```
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

will make the screen always on which will disable the lock. Remove it by using

```
     getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: If this needs to be set/cleared dynamically (e.g., based on a preference or menu choice), this is a good answer. The `android:keepScreenOn` attribute is a bit simpler if it always needs to be set.

Comment: Yes you are right,, I just wanted to add a programmatic way beside your XML solution

Answer (score 4):

Add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to some widget in your activity's layout XML file. While the activity is in the foreground, the device will not fall asleep.

Comment: This answer is better then mine.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a wake lock.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: This is not the best option for things involving a UI. A `WakeLock` is for background processing.

Comment: True, I didn't know about "keepScreenOn". Thanks.