# How can I (if at all) disable device sleep in Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I'm trying to decide whether I should go with PhoneGap or Trigger.io for a mobile app I'm about to build. One of the "must haves" is the ability to disable display sleep. I've seen various hacks for PhoneGap (`idleTimerDisabled`) and even a plugin that lets you control this directly from JS, but I've yet to find ANYTHING on this topic in Trigger.io.

So, is it possible?

Comment: Currently this not supported in version 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write a native plugin for Android and iOS to disable the device sleep. Here are useful links that should get you on the right path:

[Trigger.io native plugins](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/native/index.html)

[iOS: How to stop the device standby timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064332/ios-how-to-stop-the-device-standby-timer)

[Stop android device from sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075125/stop-android-device-from-sleeping)