# Is there a way how to disable device sleep?

Tags: javascript, html, trigger.io

Working on app now that requires some kind of timer that will countdown from 5:00 min to 0:00.  Is there a way how to disable device sleep which would break this after user defined sleep time? Any hack to accomplish this?

Comment: From an HTML5 web page?  I doubt it.  You need a native app running on the device, and permission from the user.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477902/how-can-i-if-at-all-disable-device-sleep-in-trigger-io

Comment: trigger.io contains native things to address different platform feature ... my ideas go here

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to write a native plugin for Android and iOS to disable the device sleep. Here are useful links that should get you on the right path:

[Trigger.io native plugins](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/native/index.html)

[iOS: How to stop the device standby timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064332/ios-how-to-stop-the-device-standby-timer)

[Stop android device from sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075125/stop-android-device-from-sleeping)