# How do you programmatically change the display idle timeout value in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom Android Service (with no associated Activity) that needs to implement a custom idle timeout value for turning the display off under certain conditions (not all the time).  The user can set this in Settings -> Screen -> Timeout.  I actually may want to leave that value alone and simply override this setting - that is, in my situation, I don't want the user to be able to alter the value, but when the scenario is complete, I would like to go back to using the Settings value.

Is this possible?  I'm searching, but not finding an API.  Note that this would be for ICS.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-can-i-prevent-an-android-phone-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically

Comment: this may be Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, timeInMillis);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use WakeLocks. See the example in the [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) doc