# Capturing touch events even while system is in sleep

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which requires the system to get the touch events even after the system goes to sleep mode or after the user locks the screen, I tried searching for a solution but it is hard to find one. 
Should I want to set any permissions or is there any inbuilt methods or can I override any methods to perform this functionality.

Comment: I'm not clear why we are using the native code to intercept the sleep event. Is it the only way or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm developing an app which requires the system to get the touch events even after the system goes to sleep mode or after the user locks the screen

Fortunately, this is not possible. Otherwise, the device would not be asleep, and battery life would suffer as a result.

Comment: I think the battery life is not much concerned in my app. I just want to make the app to respond for the touch event while Sleeping and when the screen is locked (using the power button).

Comment: @John: Fortunately, this is not possible.

Comment: even by the way suggested by [JScoobyCed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869907/970272)

Comment: @John: If you actually take the time to read that answer, you will see that they are telling you how to not allow the device to fall asleep. This is **COMPLETELY OPPOSITE FROM WHAT YOU SAY THAT YOU WANT**.

Comment: Yeah I got it, and can u please brief me why it is not possible?

Comment: @John: First, if the device is asleep, nothing runs at all -- the CPU is powered down. Second, you in the background cannot receive touch events, regardless of whether the device is running or not.

Comment: so there is no other way to get the touch events when the device is asleep even-though we make the CPU running (PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).

Comment: @John: No. The only way you can get touch events if if the device is fully on and you are the foreground activity.

Comment: CommonasWare is right. Mobile device OEMs also shutdown the actual touch screen hardware when the device goes to sleep (to save power). The system will not even physically measure the capacitive touch screen in this state. It is impossible to do this.

Comment: @CommanasWare: I have one comment to CommansWare...  please check this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wolf.uit.com.unlockbywave i guess this is the process running in forground and it also drain bettry. Am i Right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3723649/1012381) that shows how to prevent the phone from sleeping.
If you couple that with, say a black screen to 'pretend' the hone is sleeping but actually running your code. So your code can still intercept touch event

Then you need to install your app as a service and make it start when the device is turned on.

You will not need NDK or rooted device for that (sorry, got a short night :) )

Comment: It will work when the system goes to sleep but I want the same to work even after the power button is pressed.

Comment: Agreed. You would need to code each cases. FOr the power button, just intercept the press of if by overriding 'dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)' and compare the event to 'KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER'