# how to avoid deep sleep mode in android phone programmatically?

Tags: android

I have develop one android application which will talk to server 24*7 over WiFi  but when phone goes to sleep mode it stops talking to server means socket is getting closed so for resolving this I added code to acquire partial wake lock in service onCreate() and release it on OnDestroy() method o service so even though phone goes to sleep mode my application can talk to the server.

Problem is: If you keep the device idle for longer period (more than 8 hours ), it stops communicating with the server and WiFi turned off. I heard about deep sleep mode of device, in this case it will shutdown CPU,WiFi etc.. so how to restrict it for getting CPU and Wifi turned off?

Please help me with some sample example.

Regards,
Piks

Comment: Please improve your sentences. 4 lines for 1 (!) sentence is hard to follow...

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3723634/813951

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried full wake lock as well?

Comment: yeah, i have tried full wake lock also but it doesn't serve my purpose, i want phone to go to sleep mode but it should not turned off CPU and WiFi so that my app will be connected to the server always.