# unlock screen while in call android

Tags: android, screen

How to prevent the screen from getting locked while in call. While in video call after the timeout the screen gets locked. I notice its not the case in normal android phones that we use. Can someone provide the code to keep it unlocked while in call???

Comment: try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-can-i-prevent-an-android-phone-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Change PowerManager WakeLock setting.