# How to avoid Android screen black?

Tags: android, screen

I have developed a video player application. The app will keep playing videos (and repeat them). I want to handle it while its playing so I need the videos to be playing all the time but the android system makes the screen black automatically, lock the screen or put the system on sleep. I want to know how to avoid this from happen, i.e., my program should keep playing the video and the screen shouldn't turn black. I have found some solutions on the Internet but still its not working, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

or just:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

EDIT:
    according to this link : [How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically). You should use:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();

..screen will stay on during this section..

wl.release();
```

You also need to be sure you have the WAKE_LOCK permission set in your Manifest.

Comment: :)it has achieve the screen keep lighten ,do you know how to avoid the screen lock and system sleep?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PowerManager` to avoid system sleep

[How to use PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
```

// When app resumed or started

```
protected void onResume()
{
     wl.acquire();
     super.onResume();
}
```

in `onPause()` you should release the wake lock, to avoid draining more battery

```
protected void onPause()
{
   wl.release();
   super.onPause();
}
```

And the last, don't forget the permission

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```