# how to handle the screen brightness

Tags: android

**Is there any way by which we can keep screen always on  through out the application but  it should go  for dim also after some time and again wake up once we touch, please help on it 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Google it...what have u tried??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   //..screen will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Don't forget the permission and please google it the next time ....
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html