# Overriding the screen sleep

Tags: android

What code do I need to add to a certain activity in my app to get it to override the sleep setting of the user's phone. I want the screen to not be able to shut off during a certain activity.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use WakeLock.

Like this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "Screenlock active");
```

Then use:

```
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to force screen always on, and

```
getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to go back to default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If by "a certain activity", you mean "while a certain `Activity` is in the foreground", the easiest way is to add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to some widget in the layout of that activity. So long as that widget is visible, the screen will not turn off. This works well for things like video players. The `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` approach in the other answer contributed so far does the same thing, with more typing. :-)

Comment: Sweet Deal. I will try this. Thanks guys